# How do I insert the elements of a java script function inside a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var year_table = document.createElement("TABLE");
    year_table.setAttribute("id", "head_skill_table");
    document.body.appendChild(year_table);

var year_tr = document.createElement("TR");
    year_tr.setAttribute("id", "year_tr");
    document.getElementById("head_skill_table").appendChild(year_tr);

    for(i = 2006; i <= 2016; i++) {
        var year_th = document.createElement("TH");
        var year_cell = document.createTextNode(i);
            year_th.appendChild(year_cell);
            document.getElementById("year_tr").appendChild(year_th);
            year_th.style.width = "25vw";
            year_th.style.border = "2px dotted #a1a1a1";
            year_th.style.borderRadius = "100%";
            year_th.style.padding = "1.5% 0.5%";

        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            var year_hr = document.createElement("TH");
                year_hr.innerHTML = '<hr style="border-top: 2px dotted #a1a1a1;">';
                document.getElementById("year_tr").appendChild(year_hr);
                year_hr.style.width = "25vw";
            }
    }
    var year_th = document.createElement("TH");
    var year_cell = document.createTextNode(2017);
        year_th.appendChild(year_cell);
        document.getElementById("year_tr").appendChild(year_th);
        year_th.style.width = "25vw";
        year_th.style.border = "2px dotted #a1a1a1";
        year_th.style.borderRadius = "100%";
        year_th.style.padding = "1.5% 0.5%";
}

</script>
</head>
<body >

<div id="one">
<!--Some Content-->
</div>
<div id="two">
<!--Some Content-->
</div>
<div id="three">
<!--Some Content-->
</div>

<div id="myDiv" style="some css style">
<!--Place my table created with javascript function here, so it will inherite the css style-->
</div>

<div id="four">
<!--Some Content-->
</div>
<div id="five">
<!--Some Content-->
</div>
<div id="six">
<!--Some Content-->
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Now I want to add my code into the div with id = "myDiv" so that the table that gets created by myFunction()  will inherit all the CSS style of myDiv()
I tried innerHTML but that didn't make the table inherit the style of myDiv.

Comment: You should use CSS stylesheets.

Comment: check this fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/nrgbf14p/1/): added div have the right style applied. But a div does not inherit all the properties of its parent (see how the `border` rule is only applied to the matching div).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to drop the year_table into myDiv as done below.  I've added some styling for myDiv to make the border blue.

```html
<script>
function myFunction() {
var year_table = document.createElement("TABLE");
    year_table.setAttribute("id", "head_skill_table");
  var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
  myDiv.appendChild(year_table);
//    document.body.appendChild(year_table);

var year_tr = document.createElement("TR");
    year_tr.setAttribute("id", "year_tr");
    document.getElementById("head_skill_table").appendChild(year_tr);

    for(i = 2006; i <= 2016; i++) {
        var year_th = document.createElement("TH");
        var year_cell = document.createTextNode(i);
            year_th.appendChild(year_cell);
            document.getElementById("year_tr").appendChild(year_th);
            year_th.style.width = "25vw";
            year_th.style.border = "2px dotted #a1a1a1";
            year_th.style.borderRadius = "100%";
            year_th.style.padding = "1.5% 0.5%";

        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            var year_hr = document.createElement("TH");
                year_hr.innerHTML = '<hr style="border-top: 2px dotted #a1a1a1;">';
                document.getElementById("year_tr").appendChild(year_hr);
                year_hr.style.width = "25vw";
            }
    }
    var year_th = document.createElement("TH");
    var year_cell = document.createTextNode(2017);
        year_th.appendChild(year_cell);
        document.getElementById("year_tr").appendChild(year_th);
        year_th.style.width = "25vw";
        year_th.style.border = "2px dotted #a1a1a1";
        year_th.style.borderRadius = "100%";
        year_th.style.padding = "1.5% 0.5%";
}

</script>

<style>
  #myDiv table th {
    border-color:blue !important;
    }
  </style>

<div id="one">
<!--Some Content-->
</div>
<div id="two">
<!--Some Content-->
</div>
<div id="three">
<!--Some Content-->
</div>

<div id="myDiv" style="some css style">
<!--Place my table created with javascript function here, so it will inherite the css style-->
</div>

<div id="four">
<!--Some Content-->
</div>
<div id="five">
<!--Some Content-->
</div>
<div id="six">
<!--Some Content-->
</div>

<script>
  myFunction();
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS for styling. That's what it's designed for.

```
div #head_skill_table {
     /* my style rules */
    }
```

And change the javascript function to accept the ID of a div to place the table inside, so it stays flexible.

```
function myFunction(tableID) {
// ...
}
```

Then you can separate out your display from your structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').appendChild(year_table);
```

if I understand correctly you just need this line after your table is generated. Also dont forget to call your function sometime or in window.onload like

```
window.onload = myFunction;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the id `head_skill_table`, to make the style to effect your code

```
#head_skill_table {
  background:red;
}
```